# Firefox does not open url in service worker on Push message click

Tags: firebase, firefox, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

Firefox is not opening window in service worker to push messages.

I have everything setup, the Push messages are received fine and when I click on it, it opens new window only in Chrome, not in Firefox.

Clients.openWindow("some url") doesn't work if firebaseApp.messaging() was called due to initialization step in FireFox version 57 and greater.

```
initializeFirebase = (firebaseMessagingSettings: FirebaseMessagingSettings) => {
        this.firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp({ "messagingSenderId": firebaseMessagingSettings.messagingSenderId });

        const messaging = this.firebaseApp.messaging(); // this is the reason
        messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(this.handleBackgroundPushMessage);
}

this.scope.onnotificationclick = event => {
    this.scope.clients.openWindow(clickUri); // this makes no error, nothing
}
```

What should i do to make it works?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue. If Firefox has no browser windows open (but is running in the background), then clicking the notification does nothing. If there is a Firefox window open, then clicking the notification opens the correct page.

Comment: I too got same issue. any one has solution for this?